# Create an event subscriber to handle Error in Symfony 5.1

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

How can I create an event subscriber that fires when an `Error` like `TypeError` is thrown?

I have a controller that throws a `TypeError`. I want to create an event subscriber or listener capable of reacting to an `Error`, including `TypeError`.

Looking at [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html), I've got an event subscriber for `kernel.exception`, but this does not get called when a `TypeError` is raised.

```
class MyController {
    /**
     * @Route("/error", name="error_listener_test")
     */
    public function bad() : Response
    {
        throw new TypeError('Bad Type');
    }
```

```
class FatalEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['onException', 150], 
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $e = $event->getThrowable(); // Breakpoint here never triggers. 
    }
}
```

The [`KernelEvents::EXCEPTION`](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/5.x/KernelEvents.php) triggers a [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/ExceptionEvent.php) which accepts a `\Throwable`, so I think it should be ok to accept the `TypeError`.

I've verified that the event subscriber is registered with [the symfony console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#debugging-event-listeners):

```
Registered Listeners for "kernel.exception" Event
=================================================

 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
  Order   Callable                                                                           Priority
 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
  #1      App\EventListener\FatalEventSubscriber::onException()                                150
```

I'm stepping through in a debugger, and I know that:

- My controller throws the `TypeError`,
- My event subscriber (`FatalEventSubscriber::onException`) is not called.

How can I configure the event subscriber to fire for these events?

Comment: Looking at HttpKernel::handle one can see that only Exception is being caught and then passed on to the event dispatcher.  Not sure why they don't catch Error or Throwable.  Maybe because Errors or more of an internal PHP thing?  Have you experimented with [ErrorException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)?  Been awhile since I have dug into the bowels of Symfony error handling.

Comment: I've done a little experimenting with `ErrorException` and `set_error_handler() `, and also with [`ErrorHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/error-handler), but I haven't managed to nicely achieve a result yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your listener is not being called because you are throwing a [`TypeError`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php), which extends from `\Error` and not from `\Exception`.

`Error` and `Exception` are both instances of  `Throwable`, but are generally considered different things which represent essentially different situations (which is why `Error`does not extend `Extension`).

As explained in the [original RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throwable-interface) for the `Throwable` interface:

> Users should generally be discouraged from catching Error objects except for logging or cleanup purposes as Error objects represent coding problems that should be fixed rather than runtime conditions that may be handled.

You can [check the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22128#issuecomment-294582427) for `HttpKernel::handle()`, and see that it only attempts to catch `\Exception` events, not `\Throwable` ones.

At least [one issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22128) was opened asking to widen the scope of this `catch`, but it was, IMO, correctly [rejected](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22128#issuecomment-294582427).

TLDR: If you want your exception listener to be triggered, throw some kind of `\Exception`, no an `\Error`.

> How can I configure the event subscriber to fire for these events?

I don't think any "configuration" will let you "listen" or catch `TypeError` errors with the Symfony event dispatching system, not directly. If you want to do so, you would need to create your own error handler, and maybe convert the `TypeError` to an `ErrorException`.

For a good example on error handlig, [check how Monolog does it](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/39637a5d0e98068d98189ce48a87f3dd61455429/src/Monolog/ErrorHandler.php#L59).

Comment: Thanks. I've read the `Throwable` RFC, and my purposes here would be 'for cleanup'; I'm not explicitly throwing a `TypeError`, but it's the most common issue the library I'm using has, and I'd prefer to find a cleaner way to handle this than wrapping every controller method in a `try, catch(\Throwable)`.

Comment: In any case, you simply **can't** create an event subscriber that catches `TypeError` (or any other type of `\Error`, for that matter), because Symfony does not deal with those within it's event dispatching system. If you want to deal with those, you would need to create your own error handler. See for example how [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/39637a5d0e98068d98189ce48a87f3dd61455429/src/Monolog/ErrorHandler.php#L59) does it.

Comment: And if you are not in control of the library emitting the errors, playing around with `ErrorExcception` as suggested above won't get you anything, unless you create your own error handler to convert the `TypeError` to `ErrorException`.

Comment: Hm, really strange. I'm just reproduce such case and successfully catch any Error by `EventSubscriber`. Symfony 5 already register ErrorHandler https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-errorhandler-component in FrameworkBundle.php `ErrorHandler::register(null, false)->throwAt($this->container->getParameter('debug.error_handler.throw_at'), true);`. ErrorHandler successfully catch any descendant of `\Error`, including `\TypeError` and forward them to EventSubscriber.

Comment: @FallDi Could it be that that only works with "debug" enabled?

Comment: No. `$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']` is `false`. In addition `Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug::enable()` was not invoked. I'm just double check on fresh Symfony 5. Symfony ErrorHandler do similar job as Monolog, and handle Errors too.